# how to change style with facebook android sdk login button?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />
```

i want to change login button style with other picture, how?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fb sdk has set the button background saying

```
           this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_loginbutton_blue);
```

you should change the image in fb sdk,

replace the  drawable(com_facebook_loginbutton_blue) with your drawable in fb sdk